# DevExpress: Get Entity ID of currently selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have an ASPxGridView and in the EditForm, I have a popup form when the suer clicks a button. I need to get the ID for the currently selected entity/row so that I can query the db and populate a dropdown on the popup based on that ID. How can I get that? I know with some events, you can do this:

```
protected void myGrid_OnRowUpdating(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {
            Guid entityId = (Guid)e.Keys[0];
```

So I wanted to try that with the `SelectionChanged` event, but the event argument is only of type `EventArgs`, so i cannot use the above..

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something client-side. First, I added this column:

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" VisibleIndex="0" Width="40">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="SelectAllCheckBox" runat="server" ToolTip="Select/Unselect all rows on the page"
                        ClientSideEvents-CheckedChanged="function(s, e) { gridView.SelectAllRowsOnPage(s.GetChecked()); }" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

then I also added this (to the same grid):

```
<ClientSideEvents SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged" />
```

Lastly, the javascript:

```
var selected = [];

        function grid_SelectionChanged(s) {
            s.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
        }

        function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values) {
            selected = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                selected.push(values[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HtmlRowCreated` event to bind the contents of the dropdown as shown below.

```
protected void myGrid_HtmlRowCreated(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowType != GridViewRowType.EditForm)
        return;

    var grid = sender as ASPxGridView;
    if (grid == null) 
        return;

    var row = (sender as ASPxGridView).GetRow(e.VisibleIndex) as MyEntity;
    var ddlMyDropDown = grid.FindEditFormTemplateControl("ddlMyDropDown") as ASPxComboBox;

    ddlMyDropDown.DataSource = GetDataForMyDropdown(); // Your Business Logic
    ddlMyDropDown.DataBind();
}
```